# Javascript error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

at this line

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.lightbox-wrap').offset().top - 80 }, 800);
```

The full code is that

```
$('.lightbox-wrap').hover(function(){       
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}, function(){      
    timeout = setTimeout("$('#close_subscribe_lightbox').click();", 5000);      
}); 

*/      
setTimeout("$('.overlay').show();", 5000);      
setTimeout("$('.lightbox-wrap').show();", 5000);        
setTimeout("$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.lightbox-wrap').offset().top - 80 }, 800);", 5000);     

// to set time out in lightbox      
//setTimeout("$('#close_subscribe_lightbox').click();", 5000);
```

Comment: can you post the html?

Comment: Also, why does it look like you're closing a block comment with `*/`? Your code won't run in its current state. Please post your complete, working (ie. syntax error-free) code, so it's easier to isolate what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code indicates that your .lightbox-wrap has been hidden.
Note that the .offset() property will not work on objects hidden with `display:none`:
http://api.jquery.com/offset/

You need to make sure the object is "visible" before the function gets interpreted.